# Does `threadDelay (maxBound :: Int)` trip a GHC bug or what?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I want my program to basically lockup forever and the first idea I had was:

```
threadDelay (maxBound :: Int)
```

This gave some spurious warnings:

```
Prelude> import Control.Concurrent
Prelude Control.Concurrent> threadDelay 10
Prelude Control.Concurrent> threadDelay (maxBound :: Int)
<interactive>: c_poll: invalid argument (Invalid argument)
<interactive>: ioManagerWakeup: write: Bad file descriptor
```

Did I do wrong or did GHC?

Comment: Is this on 32 or 64 bits?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems to be a [known GHC bug](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/7325), with some progress made (though not all configurations appear to be fixed yet).

In the meantime, you could use `forever (threadDelay (2^20))` or similar as a workaround; `2^20` ought to be far enough away from `maxBound` to avoid this bug, and waking up once a second for a few cycles should be quite easy on your system.

Comment: Thanks. `forever (threadDelay maxBound)` from that bug report is a better idea than mine.

Comment: @MichaelFox I've updated the answer with a proposed workaround.

Comment: Thanks. I will do exactly that.